# over and underbrace display

Tags: overbrace, underbrace

I would like to display braces under and over the text to have such display:
[image: What I want]

However, when I use `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`, I get this result (MWE under):
[image: What I have]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \underbrace{AB}_{AB = ax^2 + bx +c}C + D\overbrace{E}^{E = d x^3 + ex^2 + fx + g}FG = HI\underbrace{J}_{J = \ln{2x}}K
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With these two functions, when the over/under formula is longer than the element of the main formula, some space is added in the main formula, which I don't want.

The second thing that would be nice would be to vertically centre the brace on the first character of the secondary formula (so for instance the tip of the brace would be centred with the `E` of `E = d x^3 + ex^2 + fx + g`, as can be seen in the first figure).

(If you have any idea to enhance the title, don't hesitate to comment and/or edit my question)

Comment: As you are using `mathtools`, you can put the text in a `\mathrlap`. What do you mean exactly by "vertically centre the brace on the first character of the secondary formula"?

Comment: Never mind, I think I understand: you mean that the tip of the brace should be centred with, respectively, AB, E, and J, right?

Comment: Yes, the tip of the brace should ideally be centred with what is before the equal sign of the sub formula.
This is however secondary, the most important for me would be not to have these spaces inside the main formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overbrace and underbrace have a minimum width that would make the display quite bad anyway; squeezing them like in the picture is even worse.

I suggest arrows pointing to a single letter, the brace for multiple letters. Using `\mathrlap` and `\mathclap` provides the other trick.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{AB}_{%
AB\mathrlap{{} = ax^2 + bx +c}
}
C + D
\overset{
  \substack{E\mathrlap{{} = d x^3 + ex^2 + fx + g}\\\downarrow}
}{E}
FG = HI
\underset{\substack{\uparrow\\\mathclap{J = \ln 2x}}}{J}
K
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mathrlap` does all for the `AB` case. That's really the command I was missing.
In deed, the brace also have a minimal size and it may not be a good idea to try going under (ie use single character), but the arrows are a good workaround.

Comment: @Togh Possibly the arrow also in the `AB` case would be good, as the letters are repeated below anyway. By the way, `\ln 2x` doesn't need braces; neither `\sin x` does and so on.

Comment: I should have added it to the MWE, but I also have several layer of under/overbrace.
The display remains nice with the arrows, but with the brace, the main formula of the brace is always in normal script size. Display can be enhanced thanks to `\scriptstyle`: `\overbrace{level1}^{ level1 \mathrlap{= ax + \overbrace{\scriptstyle level2}^{ level2 \mathrlap{= something}}}} `

Comment: right, or at the opposite, remove the repetition. I think the way you answered the example is good because it allows to chose the way to display.
`\ln x` do not need the brace, but putting some gives brace highlighting in the editor, which makes easier to find the beginning and the end with longer formula without outputting anything in the pdf.

Comment: `\underbracket` looks better than `\underbrace` for short items, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard That's another possibility.